# This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2007, hyperlink

Part of Jeff Attwood's answer to this problem back on Dec 24 10 was
Browse to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.html`.
 I do not have that entry in my registry.
When I search the registry for .html, the first result is

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html
```

(value not set) 
Next result is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.html  (Default) Opera.HTML
```

There are reference's to Opera throughout the registry. I have never installed Opera on this machine.
IE is Ver8 which seems to have some problems. deleting browsing history either locks up machine or stalls for a long time. upgrading to ver9 didn't solve the problem, so went back to Ver8. Normally would not use IE.
Avant 2010 build 130 is my default, I know it uses the IE core.
Mozilla 4 is installed

System is Dell Latitude E6410 4 Gigs Win 7 Pro. Win XP Mode

Interestingly there is no reference to Opera in the XP Mode registry. Nor does deleting temp files slow the machine.
Hyperlinking works in XP Mode Word 97

**All I want to do is use hyperlinking in Word 2007 without that message**
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Most posts elsewhere refer to hyperlinking in browser or Outlook which I don't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Control Panel>Default Programs>Set program access and computer defaults>Custom>Choose a default web browser> and set it to Internet Explorer.

Test it now, it should work.

You can change it back to Firefox after this (I have never had to change it after, so this part I am not sure about).

Comment: Thank you KCotreau.I've wasted hours trying to find that simple solution

Comment: @Koro41 You are very welcome. I actually edited my question: At first I mentioned having solved that quite a few times, but I took it out on the off chance you would not be successful. Thank you for marking it as solved, I upvoted you to bring you back to even...not sure why someone downvoted that question.

Comment: I'm new to posting and couldn't format the way that might make more sense, I think Nifle did some edits. Thanks eveyone. All works great

Comment: P.S. This error is usually more common in Outlook, which uses Word as the editor, but also generally has more links in the received e-mails than are common in a typical Word document.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this Office Outlook 2010 hyperlink problem since 1 year again. I use Windows 7 64 Ultimate and both Opera Beta (latest) and Firefox (I don't like Chrome), but far-far preferred Opera. I do not know what happened, but since yesterday I get this message. I tried everything ("Default programs" etc.), nothing worked.

Then I opened Firefox and set "default browser". Office Outlook 2010 error message vanished and everything (Facebook, Linked-in etc.) open in Firefox like earlier in Opera. Afterwards I quitted Opera beta and opened up again and set default internet browser. And know everything opens fine with Opera Beta again.